# what this mean : 'middleware' => 'auth:api'],

Tags: api, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When i use in  my progame `Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {`
doesn't works .
All users can't access for open my project and i added column in table user.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: How is this related to the question? Why didn't you mention that? What **exactly** does that mean, what have you tried and what does not work yet? Adding a token sounds fairly simple

Comment: i want to add api_token in my project , then i added column in table user , when i add in rout Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () { he doesn't works , and i want to know this part what is mean : 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], –

Comment: Where is the connection between a token, a column in any table and the code you've provided?